# tomcat8.5 と postgresql9.2 でのユーザー認証の際のパスワードの暗号化

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, md5

tomcat8.5とpostgresql9.2とを連携してユーザー認証機能を作成しようとしていますが，
DBに保存するパスワードの文字列が平文（plain text）の場合は動作の確認ができますが，
暗号化するとうまく動作しません．

以下，簡単にtomcatの設定と，DBの内容をまとめます．

$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
    username="postgres" password="postgres" 
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb" />
```

$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml

```xml
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
    debug="99"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/postgres" userTable="usr_auth" userNameCol="usr"
    userCredCol="pass" userRoleTable="auth_role" roleNameCol="usr_role"
    localDataSource="true">
      <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="MD5" />
  </Realm>
```

webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Auth Interface</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>app-usr</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>User Auth</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

DBには該当するusr_authテーブルとauth_roleテーブルを以下のように作成しています．

usr_auth

```
  列  |           型           |  修飾語
------+------------------------+----------
 usr  | character varying(40)  | not null
 pass | character varying(200) | not null
インデックス:
    "usr_auth2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (usr)
```

auth_role

```
    列    |          型           |  修飾語
----------+-----------------------+----------
 usr      | character varying(40) | not null
 usr_role | character varying(30) |
インデックス:
    "auth_role_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (usr)
```

上記のような設定で，DBには

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.sh -a MD5 hogehoge
hogehoge:1957d2b05cb99....
```

で出力された暗号列を

```
insert into usr_auth values('aaa','1957d2b05cb99....');
```

のように登録し，ロールについても対応のレコードを登録してあります．
以上のような設定ではtomcatの起動，認証ダイアログの表示は確認できましたが，
認証を通過できませんでした．

上記の`server.xml`の`<CredentialHandler>`の行をコメントアウトし，

```
insert into usr_auth values('bbb','hogehoge');
```

のように登録した場合，ログインすることができました．

DBの登録方法に問題があるのか，tomcatの設定に問題があるのか，
わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら，宜しくお願いします．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません。自己解決しました。

公式サイトをよく読んでませんでした。
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested_Passwords

DBに登録すべき文字列は、

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.sh -a MD5 -s 0 -i 1 usr:User Auth:hogehoge
```

のようにして作成すべきでした。
失礼しました。